# Windows 7 download genuine iso

Tags: windows-7, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reinstall Windows 7 if I lost my installation DVD?](https://superuser.com/questions/272141/how-can-i-reinstall-windows-7-if-i-lost-my-installation-dvd)

I bought a windows 7 ultimate key from ebay, but i want to download windows 7 from a trusted source, so is there a microsoft link for this? or else which one should I download for windows 7 ultimate.

Microsoft Windows 7 90-Day Eval VHD is available for [download here](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/Windows-7-Download-118183.html).

Another Windows 7 RTM Enterprise 90-Day Evaluation is available for [download here](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/Windows-7.shtml).

Thank You.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you may have found by now you cannot purchase Microsoft keys from ebay and expect this to be a legitimate transaction.

Windows keys cannot be sold separately from the content their refer to. I'm afraid you were the victim of a common scam. :(

In the future only purchase Microsoft products from established suppliers.

Answer (score 3):

The only downloads Microsoft offers are for MSDN/Technet subscribers. But I believe you can see the page with the SHA1 hash for the ISO and compare it with what you can get elsewhere.

For reference, the  hash for Windows 7 Ultimate from MSDN:

```
SHA1: 5395DC4B38F7BDB1E005FF414DEEDFDB16DBF610 (x86)
SHA1: 326327CC2FF9F05379F5058C41BE6BC5E004BAA7 (x64)
```

Comment: Thank You for sha1, but how can i check the sha1 before downloading the file? is there a service on which i directly paste the download link and it will give me a sha1 code.

Comment: There really isn't a reliable way to check the SHA1 hash prior to downloading.

Answer (score -1):

you can't use your Windows 7 Ultimate license with the Windows 7 Enterprise evaluation copy.

there aren't any legal downloads for Windows 7 Ultimate, unless you have a MSDN / Technet subscribtion.