# I have a legitimate license for Windows 7 but not the disc on me - can I download the ISO anywhere?

Tags: windows-7, iso-image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I download Windows 7 (legally from Microsoft)?](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft)

I think the title says it all.

There is [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/67194/windows-7-download-genuine-iso), but there wasn't much of a response and the main answer was about being scammed!

I am away from home and need to reinstall Windows 7 on my laptop. Can I get the ISO anywhere and just use the key on the bottom of my laptop?!

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/141117/is-there-a-legal-way-to-obtain-windows-7-dvd

Comment: I've seen that before - the links don't work. I should have mentioned that in my question.

Answer (score 1):

http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/7126-The-Official-Windows-7-Repository

Untouched, original MSDN ISOs.
This moment , openbittorrent is down. Right click on the torrent in uTorrent, and use the following tracker:
`http://tracker.publicbt.com:80/announce`

That's it. :)

(Don't know about Microsoft's policy. However if you download it with a legal license that is NOT piracy and if you torrent it, that's also OK assuming others ALSO have a legal license.)

Comment: That is correct, you pay for a license not for the media. As long as you have a licensed version your are good to go.

Comment: What about Enterprise edition? I have a legitimate license for Enterprise edition but from all i've read the patchers that mydigitallife.info has does not provide a change for going to ENterprise. Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for the all-in-one iso but couldn't find an untouched version.

Answer (score 0):

You may have problems. It mainly depends on manufacturer of your laptop, but there were cases where retail versions of windows didn't accept OEM keys that came with computers. It would be best to research the situation concerning manufacturer of your laptop. In some cases it is possible to make windows accept OEM key after installation, but exact procedure depends on your laptop manufacturer, as I said few times before.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going with NO.  The sticker on the bottom of the laptop is an OEM license number.  As far as I've ever seen, no manufacturer allows you to download the OEM ISO - they usually have links to order a new disk from them.

The legitimate links you usually see for Microsoft are MSDN, ActionPack, TechNet links and those ISO's are usually volume license (VL) or retail versions and require VL or retail key numbers.

The questionable links you see (torrents) can have who knows what on them - I personally wouldn't touch them ever - you can't tell if they are complete, unmodified, clean.

That said, some will tell you it sometimes works, and sometimes it does, but this is hit or miss.

Comment: -1 Starting with Vista, there is no difference between OEM and retail ISOs.