# Making a cracked or activated windows uncracked

Tags: windows-7, windows, license, windows-activation, windows-genuine-advantage

I have a PC which has windows 7 license but I installed windows from an image I downloaded and it is already activated. For validating genuine Microsoft, I need to enter my own product key but the necessary activation tools do not exist in my windows folder. What should I do?

I googled stuff but because the keywords are too broad I couldn't find a useful tool.

DAZ doesn't work, activation button doesn't show up.

[image]

When I enter my original key to Windows Anytime Upgrade, I get this error:

[image]

When I attempt using slmgr, I get this error:
[image]

I used sfc /scannow
[image: And this is the situation]
[image]

Now slmgr is existing, I entered slmgr.vbs -ipk XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX (replacing X es  with the cd key) the operation successful. Now I have installed Microsoft Security essentials, which means the problem is solved.

Main steps are here

1. Open command prompt (cmd) in admin mode
2. Enter "sfc /scannow"
3. Enter slmgr.vbs -ipk XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
4. Success

Comment: It depends on the image you used and *what* crack(s) it uses. If the image already had cracks and third-party programs pre-installed, then you need to figure out what they are and try to find out how to remove them. (I don’t think I’ve ever heard of a way of building the key into the installation files; other than perhaps `unattend.txt`, in which case you would need to [deactivate it](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+7+deactivate).) Also, the edition (Home, Pro, Ultimate, etc.) of the version you installed from the image must match the one your license is for.

Comment: I'm guessing its one of those stripped down installs that removes stuff. Honestly downloading a legit copy off microsoft and reinstalling sounds like a better option

Comment: @JourneymanGeek not an option

Comment: Why is it not an option?

Comment: @SimonSheehan it's like a relationship consultant telling the couple to divorce and get married again.

Comment: You can download full ISO files legally from Microsoft. I don't understand your reference

Comment: @ugurcode I disagree with your bounty. Super User does not condone piracy, so this question does not apply to a large audience within our community. The ideal solution is to reinstall Windows using legitimate installation media. Plus, from a security perspect as Synetech mentioned, you cannot trust a product whose "safety/tamper seal" is broken. We have listed some resources here: http://superuser.com/questions/280557/where-i-can-i-legally-download-windows-7-installation-iso-files

Comment: @iglvzx this is kinda "unpiracy". This a possible solution will save documents and installed programs.

Comment: There is a few patches in the standard Windows Updates package that are pretty good at "Ungenuineing" counterfeit Windows copies.

I've had a few home users PCs get slapped by it after I updated the system. Would be my first step, as it's quicker than downloading and  reinstalling a fresh copy from Microsoft.

Comment: *> The question is widely applicable to a large audience.*   I highly doubt that. From what I have seen, it looks more like most activation cracks use loaders or patches as opposed to pre-activated, pre-installed keys since they would be pointless because Microsoft can easily and quickly blacklist them (viz “Devil’s Own”). I suspect that, if anything, this pre-activated ISO is a rarity in the bootleg underground. (You really should have just gotten a clean ISO from MS or at least one of the “untouched” ISOs from “the scene”; at least then you could check the hash to be sure it’s not infected.)

Comment: > _You can download full ISO files legally from Microsoft. I don't understand your reference. _   Where are they exactly? Also I'm just curious how you can trust a preactivated main product like OS. Isn't it possible they has inserted other malicious codes through OS to do dangerous things like sending your data to their servers?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your Control Panel -> System, the "Windows Activation" section is totally missing. This probably
means that Activation was hacked, and that required system components have
been deleted.

Try to Run as Administrator the following command : `slui.exe 3`. It normally brings up the Windows Activation dialog.

If this doesn't work, try to run the [System Update Readiness Tool for Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821) and the [Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/upgrade-advisor), as sometimes they fix a problem or two.

You could also try `sfc /scannow`, as described in [this article](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html).

If all else fails, and you have the Windows 7 installation media, try doing Repair Install as described in [this article](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html).

If nothing works, then this version of Windows was too damaged by the crack. I suggest in this case to reformat the hard disk and reinstal Windows from scratch. It might be a good idea to do this in any case, rather than use an unknown and maybe virus-ridden image.

Comment: the steps at the end of the question solves the problem. I'll give you the boudnty reward after 19 hours because system doesnt allow me now. (it says that I can do it after 19 hours) you can help future reades by modifying your answer accordingly.

Comment: These steps still work on windows 8.1 If anybody runs into this problem again.

Answer (score 4):

You have no idea what else could have been on that ISO you downloaded, there easily could have been a rootkit or some form of trojan on it. I would recommend [downloading a ISO directly from Microsoft](http://www.mydigitallife.info/download-windows-7-iso-official-32-bit-and-64-bit-direct-download-links/). You said in your comments you are resistant to this option because you want to save documents and installed programs. Windows has built in a [very good transfer wizard](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/windows-easy-transfer) that will help you migrate all of your files and settings to the new install, just save it to a external drive before you reinstall windows. You may need to reinstall the software but most of the settings and saves for those programs should get restored.

If you are feeling confidant that you did not get a virus/trojan bundled in with your hacked copy of windows you can attempt a "upgrade/repair" install with the official ISO, that should install all of the tools needed to activate windows.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

> 1. Click on Start (the Orb) and type ‘cmd’ in the search box.
> 2. This will open Command Prompt, or you can add Command Prompt in your right-click menu.
> 3. Now type the following in Command Prompt and press Enter.
>      `slmgr.vbs -ipk XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX` (*Note: XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX should be your product key*)
> 4. Once done, type `slmgr.vbs -ato` to activate your Windows 7.

I got these steps from http://www.sizzledcore.com/2009/10/26/how-to-change-windows-7-product-key/

Comment: I dont have thaat slmgr.vbs file

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder if that could work. I suppose theoretically, if he uses DAZ's loader to install the key, then click the uninstall button to remove the custom boot-loader, it may work. But then, if that does work, why not just use a legitimate key-changer?

Comment: daz doesn't work, install and uninstall buttons are disabled

Answer (score 0):

It is likely the that version of windows that you installed does not contain the infrastructure needed to activate properly. There is nothing you can do other than get a real version of windows, and get a fresh install.

Comment: that activation section does not exist on my pc, probably because it's pre activated

Comment: @ugurcode Even if it is preactivated, it will be there (mine is an OEM licence, and it is still there).

Comment: I added a screenshot for you

Comment: Odd. Nothing I can do then (see update)