# How to make a cracked Windows installation legal?

Tags: windows, windows-activation, legal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making a cracked or activated windows uncracked](https://superuser.com/questions/438094/making-a-cracked-or-activated-windows-uncracked)

For a cracked Windows installation, how should someone proceed to make it legal?
Uninstall the cracked Windows, then install Windows with a legit CD-key; or change the CD-Key in the cracked Windows?

And might Microsoft sue someone over that?

Comment: Should be able to install a legit key and who knows what MS will do or would do. I doubt they would go after 1 person since it is like getting blood from a rock.

Comment: If it's an un-activated copy of windows, you can just go to the system icon i the control panel and enter a legit key at the bottom. If it's a cracked system, I would advise you reinstall because you don't know what viruses or rootkits came with the crack or in what ways it has broken activation.