# reinstall windows 7 starter on Acer netbook

Tags: windows-7, reinstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install Win7 from USB](https://superuser.com/questions/62193/install-win7-from-usb)

I have trouble removing preinstalled McAfee from my Acer netbook, and I was wondering what other junk they might preinstall on it.

I was thinking that just installing windows 7 starter over all that junk would be faster. I have a sticker with a serial number on the bottom. I know I need to get a 4Gb USB stick, but how do I download the installation to put on it? Are there any other gotchas I need to be aware of?

Edit: I know that removing McAfee is very involved, and I think that it is easier to just nuke and pave it over.

Comment: How to install from a USB drive has already been covered by [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/62193/). There is no official way to just download a Windows installer if you are not an MSDN or TechNet subscriber, as explained in [this question](http://superuser.com/q/67194/), so you will have to either buy legal media or borrow it from a friend. The instructions found [here](http://superuser.com/questions/151891/) on how to install Home Premium using an Ultimate disk apply to Starter Edition as well; you may need that if you can only find a disk for a different edition.

Comment: you need to know how to remove MaAfee or want to know how to install Windows starter in USB stick ?

Comment: The OEM key isn't going to allow installation because that key has to be pinged to Acer and not Microsoft, and therefore only an Acer OEM Install (actually restore) disc would need it, and even then you don't need it because the OEM key is installed in the BIOS. If you work at a place that sells Home Premium or Professional at a discount price, it's worth the $50 to spare you from the crapware.

Comment: @digitxp, that's not actually the case in Windows 7. You can install using any media you want, but if it isn't OEM media from Acer, he would have to call Microsoft in order to complete the activation, and explain to an activation rep. A disk with a signed Acer OEM SLP pre-activation would be more convenient, but any disk would work.

Comment: @digitxp: i have a sticker saying "Windows 7 Starter SNPC OA (newline) Acer Group" followed by product key. Are you saying that I will not be able to install Windows 7 Starter from a MSDN disk?

Comment: It will, but an OEM starter, I'm saying, is full of crapware. If you have an MSDN Starter disc, the sticker on the computer is irrelevant. Use the sticker that came with the disc, usually on its sleeve thing.