# Obtaining installation media for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation, installation-media

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reinstall Windows 7 if I lost my installation DVD?](https://superuser.com/questions/272141/how-can-i-reinstall-windows-7-if-i-lost-my-installation-dvd)

I've just purchased a new laptop and it comes with the whole recovery partition jobbie and allows you to create a recovery disk which is fine if you like all the pre-installed guff on the system.

Ideally I'd like to have the Windows disk so I can do a clean install.

As I own the Windows 7 license, do I have the right to a copy of the installation media from the OEM or Microsoft?

Even if it cost's a nominal amount I'd prefer that to living in recovery-partition land.

Additionally, if I used the ISO/Disk from an MSDN subscription but used my legit product key, would I be in breach of any EULA?

---

**Update**

I downloaded the ISO from an MSDN subscription and this has worked fine (it was the non-VL SKU).

I'm going to give Microsoft a ring and try to obtain original media.

Comment: Who is the manufacturer of your laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is create the recovery disks. Depending on the model and manufacture there will be multiple disks, with one of them actually being a Windows 7 disk.

Second option would be to call the manufacture of the computer and for the cost of shipping they will send you a disk. If you directly request it, they will frequently send you your recovery disks along with a standalone Windows disk.

Third option is to directly request one from Microsoft. [This Microsoft page](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;326246) will give you the contact information depending on your location to request a new disk. Depending on your situation you may need to go to various sites (linked to on the page) to obtain them.

Phone Numbers: Monday through Friday, 5:00 A.M. to 7:00 P.M. Pacific Time.
United States: (800) 360-7561
Canada: (800) 933-4750
TTY customers: Contact Microsoft at (800) 718-1599

Answer (score 1):

Depending on who built your laptop, there may or may not be a pure Windows disc available.

As far as using software from MSDN - I do not believe your product key will work with the software on MSDN as the product key is designated as an OEM code. There is a text file on the disc that designates it as an OEM, Retail, or Site "Enterprise" license and if that is modified to OEM, then you would be able to install it. Unfortunately, I would say that would be a violation of the EULA.

If you have access to an OEM disc that is manufacturer agnostic (they exist) then you would be able to install and not be in violation of the EULA.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you install all your programs, activate them, delete all of the crapware installed on the computer and then use Windows Backup to create a system restore disk.  You can save these to CD's and use them whenever you like.  Since all the software is already activated, you don't have to worry about that (as much).