# Downloading and Activating Windows 7 Starter

Tags: windows-7, windows, netbook

I have a Windows 7 starter key that came with my netbook (a Asus EEE PC 1001P). Due to a [ID10T error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID-Ten-T_Error#ID-10-T_Error), I managed to delete both Windows 7 **and** my recovery partition. Is there a place I can download Windows 7 starter, and then install and activate it? Or is my only option for Windows is to buy a new copy of Windows 7 Home or Professional?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I reinstall Windows 7 if I lost my installation DVD?](http://superuser.com/questions/272141/how-can-i-reinstall-windows-7-if-i-lost-my-installation-dvd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of these links, http://www.ghacks.net/2010/10/20/windows-7-direct-download-links/ and then use the ISO Edition Switcher to change the version you downloaded to starter so your key will work.  If that does not work then you will most likely need to buy a new edition.  I would recommend Newegg for the best price, unless your find a deal elsewhere.

Comment: Note that the ISO Edition Switcher, while slightly convenient, is not totally necessary. All you need to do is open the ISO (most compression utilities will let you do this, for example 7-zip and WinRAR) and then find and delete the file "ei.cfg". If ei.cfg is missing, then when the installer runs it will prompt you to select which edition you wish to install. This is a convenient thing to do, because then you can reinstall all editions without having to carry multiple CDs.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get a discounted price on a disk through Asus support, you would just need to find an external DVD drive or look up instructions on a USB installation.

Comment: I called them - I couldn't hear them.

Answer (score 0):

If your key is from the sticker on your computer it will work - but you have to  activate by phone. The activation procedure will lead you through that.

Comment: Question is, how do I get Windows 7?