# Install windows 7 with product key but no DVD

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reinstall Windows 7 if I lost my installation DVD?](https://superuser.com/questions/272141/how-can-i-reinstall-windows-7-if-i-lost-my-installation-dvd)

I installed Windows 7 from an original Ultimate DVD. I have the product-key but the CD has been lost. Is there any way to install it using my product key?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open cmd as adminstrator and enter the commands below
2. slmgr.vbs -ipk {insert your new product key here}
3. To activate windows after changing the key, run “slmgr.vbs -ato”