# Does Microsoft offer disk images of their products?

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, images

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Where do I download Windows 7 (legally from Microsoft)?](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft)
>   [How can I reinstall Windows 7 if I lost my installation DVD?](https://superuser.com/questions/272141/how-can-i-reinstall-windows-7-if-i-lost-my-installation-dvd)

I have a valid Windows 7 Home Premium key. I want to download an ISO so I can re-install, as I've lost the original disk. Without getting a torrent, I was looking (but couldn't find) disk images on Microsoft's site.

However, I've seen a vanilla installation disk before in an MSDN collection I saw at an old job I had. I know that the MSDN can download ISOs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here they are:

http://www.mydigitallife.info/download-windows-7-iso-official-32-bit-and-64-bit-direct-download-links/

Comment: I can't help but think this is a little bit shady, but certainly an option to consider as a last resort. It's a shame MS don't provide these kinds of links as standard, but I understand their concern. Even a product key validated download would be a great start.

Comment: @Ruairi Fullam I don't consider it shady...You either have the key or you do not. That is what counts. Those locations are the locations Microsoft uses to deliver legally purchased software.

Comment: Its not shady, they are legitimate Microsoft Links, and unless you are a MSDN or Action Pack subscriber, you will not be able to download iso's of MS products anywhere else.

Comment: I certainly don't have a problem with a difference of opinion. I just think if it's Microsoft's prerogative to offer ISO downloads of their operating systems, they should make it a lot more accessible than having to go via a third party. Perhaps it's a business decision to intentionally obscure downloads so OEMs deal with the support burden as and when it arises.

Comment: They are valid, and they have already been provided in other duplicate answers. Please see the duplicates indicated above.

Answer (score 0):

They don't as standard, although users of their Technet, MSDN or other partner services are provided with the ability to download ISO images of their products. Whether your product key for your product in question would work with MSDN style images is very hit and miss.

I have had to resort to torrents in the past as a last resort, for a legimate version of Windows. Generally speaking however, the OEM (Original Equipment Manufacturer) should provide either recovery media, or the option to create it presented very obviously.

Comment: An OEM key (sticker on the back of your Dell/HP/etc) does NOT work with an MSDN ISO image.

Comment: I've not found that to be strictly true in all cases, my guess is Windows 7 era media may well be more heterogeneous than existing, more tightly seeded Microsoft operating systems.

Comment: @Chaitan that is actually no longer true, as of Windows Vista and later. See our [Windows 7 Activation FAQ](http://superuser.com/questions/303136/windows-7-and-vista-activation-faq-how-do-language-version-64-bit-or-32-bit-a) for more information.