# Windows does not start after changing settings in msconfig.exe

Tags: windows-7, windows

I changed some settings in `msconfig.exe` on my computer. Then I booted and advanced. Then I changed my cores from 1 to 4. I'm almost positve that my computer is only 1 core and is an Intel i3. Now Windows won't start and I can't use System Restore.

---

I have tried 2 system restores and "Last Known Good Configuration".

I am running Windows 7, not Vista or XP.

Comment: Give us some more information. "Then boot and then advanced" -- what does that mean? Did you reboot? What settings did you change in `msconfig.exe` specifically? The i3 is a dual core, by the way. How does "Windows not start"? Do you get an error message? How far do you get? Please [edit] your question to include more details...

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/314439/i-screwed-up-my-cores
The new queston

Comment: @Slhck I ran Msconfig.exe, there is a boot tab and i clicked it. Then i clicked advanced options and then changed the amount of cores running from 1 to 4 and my laptop needed a restart. I got to Starting Windows and then Startup Repair comes on my screen.

Comment: You've changed the bootloader.  Any options without a separate DVD is impossible.

Comment: *I'm almost positve that my computer is only 1 core and is an Intel i3* An i3 has two physical cores and can operate in a mode such that it appears as four logical cores.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you'll be able to boot this from the harddrive.  The msconfig setting you changed is in the bootloader.  Thus the kernel stalls right at boot.

You'll have to boot from a DVD and replace the bootloader.

The setting you change is a debug setting.  By default Windows uses all your cores.  This setting was initially used to troubleshoot the HAL layer, since there are two different HALs for single and multicore processors.

I implore you to either read Microsoft's technet or get some advice before you start messing with the MSconfig settings. . .

Answer (score 0):

Try hitting F8 on boot up before Windows starts (the same as where you would select Safe Mode), and load the "Last known good configuration".

Last known good is written only after you have logged in, and since you have not logged in since, it should work.

Since that did not work, you will need to use System Restore from a command prompt in "Safe Mode Command Prompt Only". Follow this Microsoft document on exactly how to do it:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304449

Comment: @Josh Lord If neither of the above worked, I have a strong suspicion you will need to boot to your Windows 7 DVD and do a repair install. It will not harm your programs, documents, or formerly good settings, but hopefully it will fix your problem. Use the add comment to reply, not edits please.

Comment: @KCotreau I cant find my windows 7 disk...

Comment: @Josh Lord see [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/272141/how-can-i-reinstall-windows-7-if-i-lost-my-installation-dvd/272144#272144) for links to get copies of the iso from Microsoft's official digital distributor

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain Good catch. I should have mentioned those links.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue as Josh. I have 2 laptops with Win 10. I used `msconfig` to increase the number of processors on boot in advanced boot options. The first one takes much less time on boot after I made the changes. However, the second one would not boot after i did the same thing. It went to the diagnostic mode (Windows Recovery Environment). Very frustrate!

Anyway, here is what I did to solve this problem.

1. In Windows Recovery Environment (Diagnostic mode), click Troubleshoot
2. Advanced options
3. Command prompt

It goes to 'X:\Windows\System32\'. Change it to C: first, then list boot entries with 'bcdedit /v'

```
C:
bcdedit /v
```

In my case, it shows my boot entry with identifier as `{xxxx-xxxx...}` which has numproc entry

To be safe, you can write down the settings or output the existing settings to a file first in case you need to revert the changes

```
bcdedit /v > C:\backup.txt
```

I removed the numproc entry which made it use the system default value again by executing

```
bcdedit /deletevalue {xxxx-xxxx...} numproc
```

Now double check the entry has been deleted by executing the following command again

```
bcdedit /v
```

Now type "exit" then enter, then turn off the computer. Restart it again and my problem is solved.

In case you need to put back the value, you can do something like that

```
bcdedit /set {xxxx-xxxx....} numproc 2
```

You can run the following commands to get more help

```
bcdedit /?
bcdedit /deletevalue /?
bcdedit /set /?
```

I think this is a critical bug in Windows. If the settings could cause such result, they should do something like change the display settings which requires a confirm, if the settings not good or no confirm within 15 seconds or something then cancel the changes.

Hope this can help someone running into the same problem.