# re-downloading windows 7 only having my cd key

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, crash, reinstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reinstall Windows 7 if I lost my installation DVD?](https://superuser.com/questions/272141/how-can-i-reinstall-windows-7-if-i-lost-my-installation-dvd)

I recently had a hard-drive failure and had to get it replaced. Unfortunately this was the hard-drive that had all my windows files as well as my system recovery files. I'm currently using a version of windows 32bit but i need to reinstall my 64bit version. I have the cd key that came with the laptop yet the only way I can find of getting the software back is through torrents and i'd like to get it legally. Is it illegal if I torrent windows 7 home premium and use my cd key, or should i contact microsoft and have them send my one?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft hosts the ISOs at digitalriver.  Your product key is your licence to use the software, the media is just media.

Getting the ISO from torrent sources exposes you to some risk, so it is better to get them from a Microsoft affiliate.

The links for each of the ISOs is [here.](http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2009/11/download-retail-windows-7-iso-from-official-website/)

Comment: thank you very much this is exactly what i was looking for. from what i found on most forums people were saying you needed to repurchase the dvd if your pc came with an oem version of windows. im glad to see that   is not the case.

Comment: This question has already been answered, I missed it.  Please refer to the original question.