# Where to get Windows Retail CDs?

Tags: windows, windows-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I download Windows 7 (legally from Microsoft)?](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft)
>   [How can I reinstall Windows 7 if I lost my installation DVD?](https://superuser.com/questions/272141/how-can-i-reinstall-windows-7-if-i-lost-my-installation-dvd)

So I am starting a position as a contractor for an on-site tech company. They recommend having installation CDs for each OS. In the past, I'd tell customers to re-order their recovery CDs, which wouldn't work in this case.

I saw TechNet you can download full software, but that's insanely expensive [$200] for just the downloads. Is there ANYWHERE else I could gain access to just the CDs/DVDs without the licenses? I can't afford to pay $200 out of pocket for that.

Comment: $200 for Technet "insanely expensive"? Access to media for most products and two free support calls.  Seems pretty reasonable.  Especially at 2AM when you need media or help.

Comment: @Dave, it's expensive when you're paying out of pocket. And all I need are the ISO files. I'd rather not pay if I can help it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all you need is the media, I'd recommend Bittorrent, but with the qualification that you need to be very careful what you download.

Only download well-recommended files with many seeds to minimize the chance of getting a cracked copy.

Also, searching for the full and correct name of an ISO should help minimize possible malware. Then always mount the ISO's and run full scans with a few different malware tools and AV scanners just to be completely sure.

Before I worked someplace that had TechNet this is what I did for years, and taking these and other common-sense precautions I have never found I was using a bad or cracked disk.

Comment: Do you have a recommended site to search for? And yea, the idea would be to use the customer's existing license should they not have their disk.

Comment: You might look over here for the legit MS ISO downloads (which yes, are readily available): http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft

Comment: I'd just google the full name of the ISO file and add the word "torrent". For server 2008 r2 with sp1 it's: SW_DVD5_Windows_Svr_DC_EE_SE_Web_2008_R2_64Bit_English_w_SP1_MLF_X17-22580

Comment: Or [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/272141/how-can-i-reinstall-windows-7-if-i-lost-my-installation-dvd/272144#272144), same info as the other question link, but it explains more about where the ISO's are coming from.