# Check MD5 of Windows 7 installation

Tags: windows-7

I'm having a problem verifying that an installation of Windows 7 is legitimate. It passes the validation online at Microsofts website, but I want to know if there is anyway to check the actual installation.

From what I've read, MD5 is something you can check on a file and therefore, I can check the ISO. The thing is... I don't have the ISO, but I want to check if this is a good install, with no rootkits/backdoors. Any ideas?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. If it passes online validation, it's legal, but aside from that, no. If you're worried about malware, do a malware scan.

Comment: Not necessarily worried about it being valid in M$' eyes, worried about rootkits/backdoors left from a tampered ISO.

Comment: Decide how secure you want to be.  There are BIOS RootKits nowadays.  So if you're not CERTAIN you are not infected, then the only way to be as certain as possible is to get rid of the computer and get a new one.  Short of that, replace the hard drive.  Short of that, WIPE the hard drive and install from a known good media.  Short of that, run quality tools to detect such malicious software.  At the end of the day, it's a losing battle, so decide what your acceptable level of risk is and go with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no, there are [tools available](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_File_Checker) to check the [integrity of the system files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Resource_Protection) in windows. However you do not need to affect the integrity of the system files to put in a rootkit or backdoor.

If you are unsure of a computer you just got, re-format it and reinstall windows. There are [resources available](https://superuser.com/questions/272141/how-can-i-reinstall-windows-7-if-i-lost-my-installation-dvd/) if you do not have your ISO but still have a valid license key.

EDIT: If you are concerned about a tampered ISO, just get one from the last link I posted.

EDIT2: If you have a ISO already, you can see the official hashes from [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/securedownloads/default.aspx), but you need a subscription to actually download the iso's from the site.