# All components are x64 compatible, but Win 7 Install says no

Tags: windows-7, installation, 64-bit

I have an ASUS M4A785-M motherboard with an AMD Athlon II X3 425 2.7GHz processor.

Manufacturer websites say these are both x64 compatible. However, in my BIOS, I cannot find anything that would enable x64.

I have the most up-to-date build: version 1006, and the build date is 8/18/10.

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: The beta of Win 7 64 bit was version 7000.  The most recent build for Windows 7 was 7601.  So, the version you have, 1006, doesn't really match up.  Where exactly did you get your copy of Windows 7?  Because if it is an authentic install, the disc will say exactly what version it is.  If you downloaded it, then you have no way right now of knowing what you actually have, without exploring the ISOs contents.

Comment: Oh. Sorry didn't see this comment. 1006 was my BIOS build along with 8/18/10 was the build date for that update.

Comment: I cannot find my install disc at the moment. I've seen it in the past week or so.

Answer (score 0):

The ISO you have likely does not have the 64 bit version of Windows on the disk image. See [this SU answer of mine](https://superuser.com/questions/272141/how-can-i-reinstall-windows-7-if-i-lost-my-installation-dvd/272144#272144) to see where you can download a copy of the correct edition of Win 7 from Microsoft's digital distributor

Comment: Yes it actually is. Win7 x64.