# Can I format my Windows 7 Pro installation and re-install it without a CD?

Tags: windows-7, windows, formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reinstall Windows 7 if I lost my installation DVD?](https://superuser.com/questions/272141/how-can-i-reinstall-windows-7-if-i-lost-my-installation-dvd)

Can I format my Windows 7 Pro installation and re-install it without a CD? I have a legit copy of my licence key and serials etc. I just do not have a CD.

Answer (score -1):

Burn it on a USB if you have the ISO. if you have the installation files only. try making a  bootable ISO using software "nlite" out of windows files. Once you create a bootable ISO you can burn it on a USB/DVD.

Comment: Problem.. I do not have ISO

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid - Just download it from Microsoft - http://superuser.com/questions/272141/how-can-i-reinstall-windows-7-if-i-lost-my-installation-dvd