# How to reinstall Windows 7 without media after hard-drive changed?

Tags: windows-7, installation, license

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reinstall Windows 7 if I lost my installation DVD?](https://superuser.com/questions/272141/how-can-i-reinstall-windows-7-if-i-lost-my-installation-dvd)

I have had a new hard drive installed on my Toshiba c660 satellite laptop, but I have no windows.  It originally came with Windows 7, how do I get it back or reinstall please

Answer (score 0):

Lesley,

Please contact Toshiba to get a copy of your restore media.  They will usually charge about ~$25 for a copy of the dvds to be mailed to you.  These DVDs can be run when you first turn your laptop on, to take it back to factory settings.  Start by contact Toshiba and request your "recovery media."

Once you have that, it should be easy.  However if you still have questions, feel free to come back and ask them.

Thanks

**EDIT:  Here is the contact info.

Customer Support in the United States

Computers: (800) 457-7777 (toll-free) or (949) 859-4273**

Comment: If you made backup disks before you lost your hard drive, you can also use those.

Comment: @Jikag, Good point, but most people do not make them sadly.

Comment: You wouldn't recommend a clean install instead?

Comment: @LewisGoddard - No, not in this case especially.  A clean install would mean that she needs to acquire a copy of the operating system.  When technically, she is entitled to a copy of her recovery discs since she still has the laptop, the license is still good.  Plus, between software, drivers, updates, etc; she may not be comfortable with all of the work involved with a clean install.

Answer (score 0):

**I have installed Windows 7 on a blank hard-drive in a Toshiba C660.**

[This page](http://www.mydigitallife.info/official-windows-7-sp1-iso-from-digital-river/) lists the download locations for Windows 7 ISOs as hosted for Microsoft.

You should check your Windows sticker (usually located underneath your laptop) to find out which edition you own, download the matching ISO, burn it to a DVD and Install it using the Product Key on the aforementioned sticker.

You Windows sticker will look something like this:

[image: This is an example.]

Note that you will also require drivers, all of which will install on first login, but WiFi will not work so make sure you can connect via Ethernet before trying this.

Comment: This is a horrible idea.  OP, please do not follow these directions.

Comment: @francisswest - Why exactly is this a bad idea?  The links listed are the same links used by Microsoft.  This is a perfectly acceptable answer.

Comment: @Ramhound - My apologies if it seemed rude.  My assumption from reading what the OP wrote and how she wrote it, leads me to believe that doing something like this may be out of her scope.  Downloading an ISO, burning it, using her OEM key to install it on a Toshiba (notoriously difficult to find drivers for) and assuming it will all work the way she wants it to is a horrible idea in my book.  OP will be disappointed with the results.  While my choice of words was poor (horrible idea) I believe that this answer is not a good solution for this user.

Comment: @francisswest In my experience, especially recently, the four DVDs Toshiba provided me for recovery were cumbersome and packed with junk.

Comment: @LewisGoddard, cumbersome or not, they are provided for the benefit of people like the OP.  Maybe Lesley likes the programs that come with it?  Maybe the easy of just swapping a dvd back and forth a couple of times vs looking for drivers for hours, and figuring out why it doesnt work right, appeals to her.