# Unable to install window 7 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, installation

I am trying to install Windows 7 (64 bit) on my Acer desktop. I have a 64 bit processor. When I boot with the Windows 7 disc to install, it doesn't prompt me to choose between 64 bit or 32 bit and ends up installing the 32 bit version. How do I install the 64 bit Windows 7?

System info
Processor - AMD Phenom 9500 2.20Ghz (Quad core)
RAM - 4 GB

Comment: What disc do you have?  My 7 install came on 2 discs, x86 (32) and x64.  Are you sure the disc you tried has x64?

Answer (score 3):

Windows 7 generally only comes with either 32 or 64 bit on a DVD. Keys will work for either edition, but you will need to get the CD from another source.

Comment: its only one disk. I already installed with same disk 7 64 bit on my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Windows 7 doesn't ask you whether you want to install a 64 bit or 32 bit version. You'll need to use the 64 bit installation DVD. If you do not have it then download the correct one from here and use your CD key.

[Windows 7 Professional x64 (64-bit)](http://msft-dnl.digitalrivercontent.net/msvista/pub/X15-65805/X15-65805.iso)
[Windows 7 Home Premium x64 (64-bit)](http://msft-dnl.digitalrivercontent.net/msvista/pub/X15-65733/X15-65733.iso)

Source - [How can I reinstall Windows 7 if I lost my installation DVD?](https://superuser.com/questions/272141/how-can-i-reinstall-windows-7-if-i-lost-my-installation-dvd)

Comment: Exactly; the only disc I've seen that does both is not an official ISO, but has the install files for both versions on it.