# BSOD, Windows 7 cannot boot up, no CD drive

Tags: windows-7, boot, bsod

I got a BSOD and when the laptop restarted, there are no safe mode options.

My laptop doesn't have a CD drive in it, and no disks came with it. I presume that everything is under another partition of the hdd inside the laptop.

Does anyone know where/how I go from here?  I am hoping that I wouldn't have to do a clean install as I haven't saved some of my files from the laptop.  Can I do something using the USB drive?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Windows install USB. Actually it's not forbidden to download and use ISOs of Windows 7 (as long as they are not cracked, i.e. they allow you to use Windows in trial mode). You can get an ISO from one of the official retailers (like Digital River). There are links for Windows 7 ISOs on SuperUser [here](https://superuser.com/questions/272141/how-can-i-reinstall-windows-7-if-i-lost-my-installation-dvd). You can try to create a bootable USB and see if anything will work from there - an easy way to create one is to download the ISO and then use a tool such as [UNetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) You will still need your key to activate Windows, but most of the time you can find that on a sticker on the bottom of your laptop.

However most of the time a BSOD at boot means a serious hardware failure, so you might want to consider doing sending it in for RMA.

Answer (score 0):

Most laptop's have a way to get to a recovery console during start up post of the laptop. Becarefull when doing this, some are destuctive and you will loose your data. this post has some common one's Dell, Acer, etc.

[Laptop recovery commands](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f108/laptop-recovery-instructions-162525.html)

If you have access to another Win7 PC you can try this to create a Bootable USB drive to enter the win7 recovery console.

[Bootable USB win7 Recovery drive](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-repair-windows-7-from-usb-flash-drive-repair-without-installation-dvd-disc/)

It would help to know the make and model of the laptop also.

Once you can get in to a recovery  you can try the win7 "Start up repair"
or go in to the console and try other options such as "Chkdsk /r"

Comment: I have a pavillion dm3, if that helps.  i'll try the bootable usb method first. Thanks