# Dual boot new laptop win 7 / ubuntu 12.04 - 750gb + 32gb SSD

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, ubuntu-12.04, hard-drive-cache

I have just purchased a new HP dv7t-7000 and I would like to run Windows 7 / Ubuntu.

1. How do I setup the dual boot? Can I install both operating systems with an 8gb USB drive?
2. Can I still make use of the 32gb SSD? I'm unfamiliar with the efficacy of using an SSD for caching with a 750gb 7200rpm sata 3 drive. I can only see using it for windows 7 - which I have installed in order to play games.

Thank you!

Comment: Did it come with Win7 or Win8? Since you have Win7 installed already, you can simply install Ubuntu in a new partition ([can create this during setup](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)) and it will set up dual boot automatically.

Comment: I would prefer to do a fresh install of windows 7 (which it came with.) HP likes to throw in a bunch of spyware / bloat. I'm also wondering how I'm going to get the drivers - the new thing is to force users to use a 'driver suite' which basically installs bloat / runs unnecessary processes. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a fresh copy of Win7? If not, get the appropriate 64-bit SP1 ISO from [here](http://superuser.com/questions/272141/how-can-i-reinstall-windows-7-if-i-lost-my-installation-dvd) and install it first (transfer to USB using [this](http://wudt.codeplex.com), and activate using the key on the [COA sticker](http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/licensing/antipiracy/Pages/COA_hologram.aspx)). Then install Ubuntu as mentioned above. As for drivers, check HP's site for individual downloads for different hardware devices.