# c000021a BSOD on Windows 7 boot

Tags: windows-7, boot, motherboard, bios, bsod

I guess I can't since I'm getting the error message:

> The version of System Recovery Options is not compatible with this version of Windows you're trying to repair. Try using a recovery disc that is compatible with this Windows version.

I'm trying to repair a Stop: c000021a BSOD at startup.

It happened while I was trying to flash my ASUS P8P67 Pro BIOS using ASUS AI Suite program to the latest version (from 1502). The first flash "worked" but on POST it asked me to do it again which I found weird because it was only written in the update notes that the previous had to be done like this. Unfortunately I flashed it again and that's when Windows 7 wouldn't boot again and give me that error.

Long story short I broke my last mobo flashing back and forth and now I've a RMAed one with BIOS version 3207 x64.

EDIT:
Now the disc doesn't give me an error but it still can't fix the BSOD by itself. Going to look into how I can fix this with the command prompt. I have nothing else to go with other than format and reinstall all from scratch (couldn't make back ups before because Win 7 gives me hangs up with USB external HDD).

Comment: Perhaps it could be a result of it being windows 7 sp1 instead? Otherwise, any W7pro disc should be the exact same as another assuming the same revision.

Comment: To add on to what @nerdwaller said, if you need a different Windows 7 disk, there are download links at http://superuser.com/questions/272141/how-can-i-reinstall-windows-7-if-i-lost-my-installation-dvd

Comment: I'll try with the one I installed it with, otherwise got any other clues as to solve the BSOD?

Comment: Hi Jonathan! Please **register your account** here, so you can edit your posts and post comments in the future.

Comment: can you reach F8 menu? if so, try using the "last known good configuration" entry.

Comment: Maybe change in BIOS: AHCI<->IDE (maybe:P)

Answer (score 0):

ASUS AI Suite seems to a Windows program. What i have noticed is that flashing the BIOS via Windows is a huge risk. I never do it. Flashing a BIOS is a last resort for fixing problems.

It is best to create a bootable floopy disk / CD / USB instead. Yes it a bit of messing around, but less likely to cause problems.