# Cannot start Windows 7 repair, says different system version

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I repair Windows 7 pro with a different Windows 7 pro disk?](https://superuser.com/questions/522780/can-i-repair-windows-7-pro-with-a-different-windows-7-pro-disk)

I use the exact same image I used to install Windows 7, but I get this error message when I try to start a system repair from the installation USB drive.

```
The version of System Recovery Options is not compatible with this version of
Windows you're trying to repair. Try using a recovery disc that is compatible
with this Windows version.
```

Why?

Comment: Maybe you have a Win7 RTM disk, but now you've installed the Sp1 for Windows 7. This can cause this message.

Comment: Yes, I installed all updates including some service pack. But why wouldn't it work? It's still the same major version. Breaking recovery with each SP would be just plain stupid.

Comment: @Erik Aigner now you have the cause (RTM = Build 7600 and Sp1 = Build 7601). The solution is to get a ISO with Sp1 integrated. There are ISOs available on digital river. Google for them.