# Is there any difference between download Windows 7 ISO bootable or create one myself?

Tags: windows-7, iso-image

In order to get Win7 ISO bootable it can be obtain from Microsoft download or create one by myself like [this tuturial](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-create-and-make-bootable-windows-7-iso-from-exe-plus-setup1-box-and-setup2-box-files/) .Assuming that both of them are same version ,  is there any differnce at installation between them ?

Comment: You mean, taking the Digital River EXE and converting to ISO, compared to an ISO you can download directly from MS or [Digital River](http://superuser.com/questions/272141/how-can-i-reinstall-windows-7-if-i-lost-my-installation-dvd)? No, I don't see how the *end product* that gets installed (or even the installation process) will be any different (even if the EXE>ISO might not be a bit-for-bit match for the original ISO).

Comment: Without knowing exactly where you would be downloading this Win ISO bootable that you would obtain from Microsoft, it is impossible to answer whether or not it would be the same.  Chances are, the download obtained from Microsoft would actually be from Digital River, since they host and serve the files for Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no difference. The method in the tutorial extracts and prepares the same files that would be on the ISO (try browsing the folder structure of the ISO, it would be identical).