# Install Windows 10 from an unbooted OEM drive into Virtualbox?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, external-hard-drive

I just bought a new laptop.  The first thing I did was take out the unbooted OEM Windows-10 hard disk and put in my pre-existing Linux hard disk from my last laptop.  So far so good.

The OEM drive is now attached to my (new) laptop via USB, and I see 5 partitions:

```
/dev/sdb1        2048     534527     532480   260M EF00 EFI System
/dev/sdb2      534528     567295      32768    16M 0C01 Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb3      567296 1918849023 1918281728 914.7G 0700 Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb4  1918849024 1920856063    2007040   980M 2700 Windows recovery environment
/dev/sdb5  1920856064 1953511423   32655360  15.6G 0700nMicrosoft basic data
```

What I'd **like** to do is take that hard disk and import the image(s) somehow into VirtualBox 5.2.8 (in a dynamic-sized vdi, because I don't have 1TB to spare) as though I had booted the laptop for the first time the way Microsoft expected me to.  Ideally, this would leave the actual hard drive in its current pristine and unbooted condition.  Unfortunately, between VirtualBox, UEFI, and the lack of installation CD, I don't know how Windows gets installed anymore.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do, and if so, can somebody guide me?

(At this time, I'm not looking at licensing issues.  I'll jump off that bridge when I come to it.  Right now, I just want to install.)

Comment: If you’re not worried about licensing issues, what would be the purpose of doing this? Anybody can download the windows media creation tool and create an .iso file to install Windows 10, on any computer or virtual machine. Unless you actually want the completely useless, mostly hardware specific junk the OEM included with your laptop, I can’t imagine why you want to do this. Btw, even if you clone your drive and boot it on a VM it won’t be licensed and won’t be any more useful than a trial of Windows 10 is. The license is embedded in the hardware of your laptop.

Comment: @Appleoddity That's an interesting question.  I figured: I don't currently have anything running Windows 10, I'm not familiar with it, I've (probably) paid for it in the price of my laptop, I don't use or want Windows enough to purchase a license out-of-pocket, I didn't realize the license is embedded in the laptop itself (i thought it was just a code i typed in)...  so it's very possible that I'm just using outdated knowledge and asking the wrong question.

Answer (score 15):

You can activate **Windows 10** using the product key for your hardware which is embedded in the BIOS in an ACPI table called MSDM (*Microsoft Data Management*). You can get it like this (from Linux, of course!):

```
$ sudo tail -c +56 /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/MSDM
ABA2D-TEFJ4-D97PT-9B42Y-H3U5E
```

You can apply the OEM Windows license to a VirtualBox guest like this (from the Linux host - assuming VM is called `win10`):

```
$ sudo cat /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/MSDM > ~/VirtualBox\ VMs/win10/msdm.bin
$ VBoxManage setextradata win10 \
               "VBoxInternal/Devices/acpi/0/Config/CustomTable" \
               ~/VirtualBox\ VMs/win10/msdm.bin
```

With that in place, Windows will not ask for a product key during installation, it will activate automatically. If you want to verify that it does indeed use the correct key you can use a tool like [ShowKeyPlus](https://github.com/Superfly-Inc/ShowKeyPlus) to check it. You can [read about ShowKeyPlus on TenForums](https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/2577-showkeyplus.html) or [download it here](https://github.com/Superfly-Inc/ShowKeyPlus/releases/download/ShowKeyPlus6594/ShowKeyPlus1.0.6594.zip).

This method of activation works fine with the [official download ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10ISO) that you can download for free from Microsoft. Because you can use your OEM license with a clean install, I wonder whether migrating is worth the bother.

The other way to do it which also works is to get the key as shown above and then type it in when Windows asks for it. I used this method with KVM/QEMU because I haven't (yet) worked out how to apply the MSDM table to it.

On the subject of licensing... The [Windows OEM license](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Useterms/OEM/Windows/10/Useterms_OEM_Windows_10_English.htm) (which, as I write, was last updated July 2017) suggests that it is allowed:

> **Applicability.** This agreement applies to the Windows software that is preinstalled on your device...

and, in particular, section *2.d.iv*:

> **Use in a virtualized environment.** This license allows you to install only one instance of the software for use on one device, whether that device is physical or virtual. If you want to use the software on more than one virtual device, you must obtain a separate license for each instance.

So you can install **one instance of the Windows software that is preinstalled on your device for use on one device, whether that device is physical or virtual
.**

Also see [this Microsoft community question](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/convert-windows-10-activation-to-virtual-machine/284089e3-af42-4b42-acb6-1e63d50a4212) which explains how to activate.

*I will update this answer with further information when I have any*

PS. There is [another similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/546510) here on SuperUser, and [another one](https://serverfault.com/questions/766808) over on ServerFault.

---

*The product key in the example is not real!*

Comment: This was helpful

Comment: I was searching for just this. It is really helpful

Comment: After this steps the license number showed up, but it still was not activated. In the activation windows had a link with 'problems on activation' that opened a chatbot and through there I was able to active windows with specific code given (like the one through the fone).

Comment: What if I don't have such MSDM file at the /sys/firmware/acpi/table ? There are other files tho, but none of them has the name MSDM. They have names like PCCT, MCFG, FACS, BGRT and dozen of others. They varies in size too... I'm on debian 11 system.

Comment: I think that would mean that you license key is not in the bios. Certainly the case on older hardware pre windows-10 era. Not sure if there would be another reason.