# Windows 7 install BSODs on two different hard drives on new computer

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, bsod

- **Computer**: Asus CM1740 ([newegg stats](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16883220162)), no stock HDD (stock is a 1TB SATA 6.0 GB/s -- according to a topic I found on HelpOwl, it may be Seagate or Western Digital). It was hardware and stress-tested prior to my purchase.
- **Primary hard drive**: Seagate Barracuda 7200 RPM 3.0 GB/s SATA 160 GB (from old computer -- original Windows 7 boot failure, Windows 7 disc boot failure)
- **Secondary hard drive**: Western Digital Caviar SE 7200 RPM 3.0 GB/s SATA 160 GB (also from old computer -- older Windows 7 install failure, new 2kpro install OK, new Windows 7 install failure) -- this is the primary HDD I've been working with, though I did try with the Seagate .
- **OS**: Win7 Home Premium x64 (same as stock)

I got a new (to me) computer, no HDD. I am getting two errors consistently and cannot install Windows 7 or boot from its disc. The page fault error is more prevalent. The errors are occuring when I get to the Windows 7 graphical boot screen -- the one with the Windows logo and colors, etc.

- Seagate: I tried just putting it in, no changes.
- Seagate: I tried to boot in Safe Mode, it stopped going during the loading of drivers.
- Seagate: I tried using the Windows 7 disc to get into startup recovery.
- Western Digital (exclusive HDD from here on in): I tried putting in the HDD and using the Windows 7 disc to do a fresh install.
- Reformatted with Windows 2000 Pro and installed. It worked! I cannot use an old and unsupported OS, though.

Technical codes (not sure exactly which step of troubleshooting these came from, sorry):

```
PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA: STOP: 0x00000050 (0xFFFFFA8000F400000, 0x0000000000000001, 0xFFFFF80000CE82139, 0x00000000000000002)

IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL: STOP:0x0000000A(0x000000000000000B0, 0x00000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000, 0xFFFFF8000CE80ABF)
```

**Notes**:

- It works in Win2kpro, and also works sitting on the BIOS screen. It also let me run memtest. In general, it seems fine as long as I am not trying to get into Windows 7.
- I was thinking it was the memory, but memtest + Windows memory test both say my RAM is fine.
- I was thinking it was the BIOS, but I have the latest version appropriate to Windows 7. Shall I try to flash it anyway? The motherboard says BIOS rev 1.04 and the screen says V0901 x64 5/18/2012.

**Update**: I switched SATA cables. Got to Windows 7 graphical installation screen. Clicked "Install". It went for a second and gave a new BSOD:

```
SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION:
STOP: 0x0000003B (0x00000000C0000005, 0xFFFFF9600001BD408, 0xFFFFF88004D8B680, 0x0000000000000000)

win32k.sys Address FFFFF9600001BD408 base at FFFFF960000010000 DateStamp 4a5bc5eo
```

**Update 2**: Other small things I have also tried:

- Switching the mouse (USB and PS/2 tried); removing the mouse; switching the keyboard (USB and PS/2 tried); switching monitors
- Double checking and securing all internal connections

When I switched the keyboard to PS/2 and used a newish wireless mouse, I actually got further on the Windows 7 installation than I had before. I went into system recovery tools. CHKDSK returned no errors (as expected). It was able to sit on this screen for quite a long time. I clicked install -- but about 30 seconds in, another error. Technical codes:

```
ACPI.sys PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA
0x00000050 (0xFFFFFA8000F400000, 0x00000000000000001, 0xFFFFF88001146BDF, 0x00000000000000002)
ACPI.sys - FFFFF88001146BDF base at FFFFF8800111C000 DateStamp 4a5bc106
```

**Update 3**: I downloaded Windows 7 Service Pack 1 as suggested by JourneymanGeek. I created a bootable USB flash drive with Rufus; I encountered another BSOD during the initial "loading files" portion of the install.

```
IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL

STOP: 0x0000000A (0x000000000000000B0, 0x00000000000000002, 0x00000000000000000, 0xFFFFF8000CE28ABF)
```

Comment: same disk? I wonder if the problem might be with the installer dvd rather than the drive.

Comment: Indeed, same disc. That is an excellent thought -- I have used this disc before, though. In fact, quite recently -- I reformatted my old computer less than two months before this and experienced no problems whatsoever. I read elsewhere that the ISO can be taken from the CD and placed onto a bootable flash, but I am uncertain as to the legality of this practice. Also, if the CD is damaged, taking the ISO probably won't help.

Comment: There's legal places to download ISOs - see http://superuser.com/questions/272141/how-can-i-reinstall-windows-7-if-i-lost-my-installation-dvd and an *official* tool for bootable flash - thw windows 7 usb download tool. Its *entirely legitimate*. If nothing else, you can compare md5 sums to ensure your disk is dine.

Comment: Oh! Wonderful, I had no idea. This is a very promising answer, as I feel the hardware is pristine. Thank you very much; I will report back with the results.

Comment: No luck. Downloaded SP1 ISO, created bootable USB with Rufus, and got the IRQL BSOD again. Updated my question to reflect new information. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Try resetting your bios back to factory defaults. If that doesn't help try removing/disconnecting any non-essential devices (eg hard-disks). You could also try install some other modern Operating System (Vista/Windows 8/Linux) to test your hardware. Despite your memory passing tests, it is still possible for it to be the problem (I've heard it said that the best way to test your memory/hardware is to run through the Windows Installation process)

Comment: Thank you! I did reset the BIOS to defaults, and the computer is running with CD drive, hard drive, keyboard, and monitor -- barest essentials, I believe. I don't have a Windows Vista disc, but Linux is certainly an option. I will also run Prime95, as that is said to be a better test than even memtest86. Good ideas, thanks.

Comment: Could it be rufus?  Could we try with another DVD or a liveusb made with the usb download tool?

Comment: I don't have another DVD, unfortunately. I made a USB with the download tool. This resulted in an IRQL error, though I was able to get to click the Install button again. Presently creating a Debian USB with Rufus. Other suggested options: trying a 32 bit Windows 7, putting in graphics card to override integrated. The only graphics card I have, though, is 5 years old and in poor condition. Apprehensive about placing it into this system.

Answer (score -2):

Plug drives into another PC, use HDSEntinal to verify they are 100%. It's most likely your RAM that is loose / faulty. Test it with Mem86 for 12hours. Red = error which means its time to buy new RAM/