# USB live boot into any windows OS?

Tags: windows-8, boot, usb, livecd, liveusb

I want to boot from a USB stick into a windows OS (any), however I can't find an ISO that will work on my USB. I have found [pe builder](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/) but its a windows program and I am on linux.

Could anyone link me to a download for windows (iso or equivalent) I can use to boot on USB?

I need to boot into windows (but not install it) so I can use a [key finder application](http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/) (which only work on windows) to find the windows 8 product key of the machine. (NB product key is not on the back of the machine on windows 8). I am trying to find this key as I am currently no longer able to boot into windows 8. Once I have the product key I should be able to restore the machine back to windows 8.

Comment: What are you trying to solve? Would it be easier to take out the hard disk and hook it into another machine where you can run the application? How many times (and on how many different machines) would you need to use this Live USB drive?

Comment: This has been asked and answered http://superuser.com/questions/272141/how-can-i-reinstall-windows-7-if-i-lost-my-installation-dvd I don't advise `Magic Jelly Bean` I have found it provides the wrong serial numbers for certain applications.  `belarc advisor` has never failed me

Comment: This can only be done on Windows 8 Enterprise officially, it is called Windows to Go....

Comment: @TheX - I am sure he would accept any version of Windows.  But I am not sure what good that woudl do.  Magic Jelly Bean wouldn't be able to detect the key on his other instalation more then likely.

Comment: Oh I see...you could just stick the drive in a working computer and use Magic Jelly Bean from there... you would have to load the hive...