# Fresh Windows 7 install without Windows DVD

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-installation

I have two PCs.  One with a purchased copy of Windows 7 Ultimate, and the second with an OEM of Windows 7 Home Premium (not Personnel).  I have the Ultimate DVD, but can't find the Home Premium DVD.

Everything from now on relates to only the PC with the Windows 7 Home Premium OEM.

I did a fresh install several years ago, so must have had something, but I don't recall what I did.  I have the Windows 7 HP recovery DVDs (quantity of 2), but don't want to install all the HP stuff.

How can I initiate a fresh Windows installation?

Comment: You download the ISO and burn a copy of the disk yourself.  You won't be able to use the Ultimate disk to install Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: @Ramhound.  Think the HP System Recovery DVDs will work?  Where would you recommend downloading the ISO?  Thanks

Comment: @uuser2161003 - Download it from Microsoft's digital partner.  There already exists a question with links on this very website.

Comment: That being Digital River? http://superuser.com/questions/272141/how-can-i-reinstall-windows-7-if-i-lost-my-installation-dvd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you mean Professional and not Personnel. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Either way, there is an easy way to maybe do this without any downloads. First you'll need to copy the contents of the mounted DVD into an USB drive (formatted in FAT32 and empty) by running:

```
xcopy DVDLetter:\*.* /e/h/f USBLetter:\
```

Once it's done browse the flash drive and inside the sources folder you'll find a file called ei.cfg. Delete it. That will allow to choose any version available on that medium from Ultimate to the most basic one. When you're done just boot from the USB and you'll be able to install the version you require. **If it doesn't boot, try another USB drive**, I've had problems with certain flashdrives before.

Hope this helps.

*Note: This only works with a regular Windows 7 Ultimate installation DVD.*

Comment: Sorry, I meant Home Premium.

Comment: It should still work :)

Comment: So, Windows 7 Home Premium will also be on the Windows 7 Ultimate CD?

Comment: From my experience, yes.

Comment: This link describes the same.  Thanks!  http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-select-any-edition-or-version-sku-of-windows-7-to-install-from-single-edition-dvd-disc-media-or-iso/

Comment: If you have an answer to http://superuser.com/questions/736279/modify-and-copy-dvd, please advise.  Thank you

Comment: @user1032531 - The duplicate question already goes into detail