# Modify and copy DVD

Tags: linux, windows, dvd

I have a existing DVD (happens to be Windows 7), and I would like to copy it to another DVD.  Before doing so, I would like to slightly modify the content by deleting a single file.  I can either use Linux or Windows.

How can I do this?

Reference [Fresh Windows 7 install without Windows DVD](https://superuser.com/questions/736260/fresh-windows-7-install-without-windows-dvd) for why I wish to do this.

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How I do to modify the contents of a ISO file?](http://superuser.com/questions/102384/how-i-do-to-modify-the-contents-of-a-iso-file) [How do I edit bootable ISO files in Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/333870/how-do-i-edit-bootable-iso-files-in-windows) Try checking if those solutions work.

Comment: @Canha.  The recommended answer will not work as the iso is too large.

Comment: Please check the other answers on both questions as they will probably solve the problem, you might have to do some trial and error :)

Comment: You might want to offer a bounty on the other question if you want more/better answers.  http://superuser.com/help/bounty

Comment: code.kliu.org/misc/winisoutils/  This has the necessary utility to convert the cdrom into an 'all-in-one' style.  It does not add the key or anything, just removes the automatic selection of a particular version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an image (with magiciso or any other program) of the DVD.
Open it up with any archiver, delete that file.
And burn that image to another DVD.