# Checksums for Win7 installation files?

Tags: windows-7, iso-image, hashing, md5

OK many thanks to the guys on [Where can I download Windows 7 (legally from Microsoft)?](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft) who provided links to d/l the WIn7 .ISO images.

Now where can we find a similar listing of the md5 hashes for those files? [I was using one of those downloads and was beating my head against a wall because of an error during file unpacking - turned out my image was corrupted. Downloaded again and it worked perfectly - could have saved myself 2 days of frustrated googling and lots of hair if I had just checked the hashes before starting :-( ]

I managed to find one or two md5 nos but not for the specific file I'm looking for. Someone somewhere must have them all? I'd have thought the Digital River d/l site probably has them but I haven't yet found a way to access the parent pages of any of those downloads - the links in the page I referred to above all take you direct to the downloads.

Comment: The checksums have not been posted.  Feel free to download each one, calculate the checksum,and post it for the community.

Comment: TechNet should provide SHA-1 hashes. http://superuser.com/questions/272141/how-can-i-reinstall-windows-7-if-i-lost-my-installation-dvd lists hashes for English ISOs. That also has links to the TechNet pages with hashes (click on the `Details` link).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SHA1 checksums [are available from microsoft.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/default.aspx?pv=36%3a350#searchTerm=&ProductFamilyId=350). If you found the file you're interested in, click "Details" to see the checksum.

I found a list of MD5 sums [on a page with torrent links](http://mirror.corenoc.de/digitalrivercontent.net/), but the official Microsoft sources are probably more trustworthy.

Comment: "SHA1 checksums are available from microsoft". Not anymore, apparently.